# Сортировка методом выбора C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Есть два массива одинакового размера, один заполнен числами, второй пустой. Нужно методом выбора отсортировать первый массив во второй, не изменяя первый. При этом, не копировать первый массив во второй.

Comment: искать пробовали? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы элементы добавлялись во второй массив, первый не изменялся.

Comment: и что? там переделка алгоритма в 1 строчку

Comment: Хорошо, так? b[i] = a[min]

Comment: проходите 2 циклами от 0 до N, при каждом проходе находите максимальный элемент и вписываете его во второй массив в обратном порядке, игнорируете элементы больше последнего перенесенного во второй массив вот и все

простой же алгоритм с временим O(n^2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот есть же википедия, есть ссылка

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC

Раз требуется не менять первый массив, то почему бы не хранить во втором индексы по первому массиву и переставлять не элементы первого массива, а индексы второго массива?

```
void studip_sort(int* src, int* dst, const int size) {

    // поставить каждому элементу dst его индекс
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        dst[i] = i;
    }

    // отсортировать массив
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        int min_index = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (src[dst[j]] < src[dst[min_index]])
            {
                min_index = j;
            }
        }

        if (min_index != i)
        {
            const int tmp = dst[min_index];
            dst[min_index] = dst[i];
            dst[i] = tmp;
        }
    }

    // поставить каждому элементу dst значение из src
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        dst[i] = src[dst[i]];
    }
}

int main() {

    int src[20] = { 1, 6, 9, 11, 0, -3, 4, 5, 11, 6, 7, 7, -8, 11, 20, -11, 0, -3, 1, 5 };
    int dst[20];

    studip_sort(src, dst, 20);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        std::cout << dst[i] << " ";
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Суть заключается в том, что нужно находить минимальные элементы в первом массиве и добавлять во второй, по порядку. Как мне при переборе избегать уже добавленные элементы?

Comment: @doomer - а если 2 одинаковых минимальных элемента? Есть сортировка выбором - если ее требуют, ее и используйте - приведенный код сортирует индексы, а потом вместо индексов ставит значения, в результате ВСЕ условия задачи выполняются - сортировка выбором, не меняется исходный массив, не копируется первый массив во второй - кстати если оставить только сортировку по индексам, то вообще в принципе никакого копирования не будет